# Console log not reflecting all requests; jQuery not displaying in html

Tags: jquery

Brain is just melting. I can't figure out why my numbers aren't showing up on the HTML.  First, which is something that I didn't know, I switched the order of my Bootstrap and jQuery links on my index file and that helped fix a complete mystery, and I fixed all of my many syntax errors, and now I am not getting any errors in the console, but I also it is not logging my console.logs.  When I hover over my addValues function and my click function, they both say "void", but I can't find my errors and can't figure out why it isn't logging to the console. I am a learning developer....

```js
//global variables
var crystal = {
    purple:
     {
        name: "purple",
        value: 0
    },
    green: {
        name: "green",
        value: 0
    },
    orange: {
        name:  "orange",
        value: 0
    },
    star: {
        name: "star",
        value: 0
    },
};

//Scores 
var yourScore = 0;
var targetScore = 0;

//Wins and Losses
var winCount = 0;
var lossCount = 0;

//functions
//math function so that we can get some random numbers
var getRandom = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

// Starts the game
var startGame = function() {

//Resets the current score 
yourScore = 0;
 
//sets the new Target score (between 19 and 120)
targetScore = getRandom(19, 120);

//Sets the rand values for each crystal (between 1 and 12)
crystal.green.value = getRandom(1, 12);
crystal.orange.value = getRandom(1, 12);
crystal.purple.value = getRandom(1, 12);
crystal.star.value = getRandom(1, 12);
  
// jQuery to add input to the HTML
$("#your-Score").text(yourScore);
$("#target-Score").text(targetScore);

//Is any of this working?
console.log("Target Score: " + targetScore);
console.log("Green: " + crystal.green.value + " | Orange: " + crystal.orange.value + " | Purple: " + crystal.purple.value +  " | Star: " + crystal.star.value);
console.log("---------------------------");
};

//Check if we won or lost and reset the game
var checkWin = function() {

//do your if you lose
    if (yourScore > targetScore) {
        alert("Sorry, you lose.");
        console.log("You lost.");
    

    //add to loss counter
        lossCount++;

    //change the html
    $("#loss-Count").text(lossCount);

    //Restart the game
    startGame();
    }
    else if (yourScore === targetScore) {
    alert("Congratulations! You won!");
    console.log("You win.");
    //add to win counter
    winCount++;

    // Change the win count in HTML through jQuery
    $("#win-Count").text(winCount);

    //Restart the gaem
    startGame();
    }
};

//when you click on the crystals there should be a value added...
var addValues = function(crystal) {

 //Change Your Score
 yourScore =+ crystal.value; 
 
 //Add jQuery to connect to html
 $("#your-Score").text(yourScore);

 //calling the checkWin function
 checkWin();
 //is it working? no. it is not. :(
 console.log("Your Score: " + yourScore);
};
//main process

//starts the game the first time.

startGame();

$("#purple").click(function() {
   addValues(crystal.purple);
  
});

$("#green").click(function() {
   addValues(crystal.green);
});

$("#orange").click(function() {
   addValues(crystal.orange);
});

$("#star").click(function() {
   addValues(crystal.star);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <!--JQuery style sheet-->
     <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
     integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <!--JS file link-->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="assets\javascript\game.js"></script>
    <!--Bootstrap stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
    <title>Crystal Game</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">   
  <!--Game heading using bootstrap jumbotron-->
    <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:rgb(166, 83, 245); color: white">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="text-center">
                <strong>Crystal Collector Game</strong>
            </h1>
        </div>
    <!--Game Instructions-->
    <div class="row">
        <!--Instructions container-->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card-mb-4">
                <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(255, 189, 47)">
                    <h3 class="card-title text-center">Instructions</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="text-center"><small>You will be given a random number at the start of the game.<br>
                    There are four crystals below. Click on a crystal to add points to your total score. Win the game by clicking the crystals to match the random number.  Lose the game when you click a crystal and the number goes over the random number. The value of each crystal is hidden from you until you click on it.<br>
                    For each new game, the random number changes and the value of each crystal changes.<br>
                    Good luck!</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    <!--Scores and Crystals-->
    <div class="row" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card-mb-4">
                <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(255, 189, 47)">
                    <h3 class="card-title text-center">Target Score</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="text-center" id="target-Score">0</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Your score-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card-mb-4">
                    <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(255, 189, 47)">
                        <h3 class="card-title text-center">Your Score</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="text-center" id="your-Score">0</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Wins Count-->
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card-mb-4">
                    <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(255, 189, 47)">
                        <h3 class="card-title text-center">Win Count</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="text-center" id="win-Count">0</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!--Loss Count-->  
        <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card-mb-4">
                    <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(255, 189, 47)">
                        <h3 class="card-title text-center">Loss Count</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="text-center" id="loss-Count">0</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
            
        
        <!--Crystals-->
        <div class="card-mb-6">
            <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(255, 189, 47)">
                <h3 class="card-title text-center">Crytal Count</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row" style="width: 100%"> 
                    <img id="purple" class="col-md-3" style="height: 25%" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/dynastywarriors/images/4/4a/Amethyst_5_%28DWU%29.png">
                    <img id="orange" class="col-md-3" style="height: 25%" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/460/460852.png">
                    <img  id="green" class="col-md-3" style="height: 25%" src="https://mbch.guide/wp-content/uploads/crystal_free.png">
                    <img id="star" class="col-md-3" style="height: 25%" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apavlinovic/pokemon-go-imagery/42a8d6aaad6d95ef0753fe80b4ddd168dd05908e/images/starpiece.png" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    



  </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do we have to click or hover to see the issue?

Comment: on the javascript file it was showing => void and the random numbers were not shoing up on the html.  I received another answer that solved the issue.  I needed a $document.ready(function () to surround my jQuery click function.

Answer (score 1):

The click events are not working because the JavaScript is running before the elements are rendered. You could fix this by putting the events inside a document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#purple").click(function () {
        addValues(crystal.purple);
    });

    $("#green").click(function () {
        addValues(crystal.green);
    });

    $("#orange").click(function () {
        addValues(crystal.orange);
    });

    $("#star").click(function () {
        addValues(crystal.star);
    });
    startGame();
});
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/